# Template to unpack arguments to a std::function

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, variadic

I am writing some C++ code to interact with an external scripting language. I want to be able to register arbitrary C++ callable code as functions to be called from the script.

The scripting library offers an API to register function pointers with signature

```
std::string callback( std::vector<std::string> const& args);
```

ie any function called from the script is given an array of strings representing the functions input args and expects a String as a result.

Up to now I would create a wrapper function for each c++ function I want to expose to the script.
e.g. for function

```
int add_two_numbers(int a, int b){ return a + b; }

//I create and register

string add_two_numbers_wrapper( std::vector<std::string> const& args)
{
    auto arg0 = std::stoi( args[0] );
    auto arg1 = std::stoi( args[1] );

    auto result = add_two_numbers( arg0, arg1 );

    return std::to_string(result);
}
```

Not wanting to write the wrapper by hand each time I've tried to create some templates to manage the boilerplate. I had some success using a number of template wrappers that are written for each set of different argument counts but I want to support 'any' number of args in future without creating a new template.
This is my attempt at a one-size-fits-all function wrapper template.

Are there anyways of simplifying further?
I'm not too bothered about performance at this juncture and the priority is ease of use.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


///Helper Template to convert to and from the script's value types.
//should support functions:
// from_arg   - convert string to expected c++ argument type
// to_result  - convert result back to script type.
template < typename TType > 
struct convert_type;

//specialisation for int
template <> struct convert_type <int >
{
  static int from_arg (std::string const &arg)
  {
    return std::stoi (arg);
  }

  static std::string to_result (int r)
  {
    return std::to_string (r);
  }

};


template <> struct convert_type<void>
{
    static std::string to_result()
    {
        return "";
    }
};


//Wrapper template for adapting c++ function to function that is callable from script
template < typename > class fun_wrapper;

template < typename R, typename ... Args > 
class fun_wrapper < R (Args ...) >
{
public:

  using FunctionType = std::function < R (Args ...) >;
  using ResultType = R;
  using ArgTypes = std::tuple < Args ... >;

  static constexpr int m_arg_count = sizeof ... (Args);

  //constructor
  fun_wrapper (FunctionType f)
  :m_fun {f}
  {
  }

  std::string operator ()( std::vector<std::string> const& inputs)
  {
    
    if constexpr( std::is_void_v<ResultType> )  //wrapped function returns void
    {
        if constexpr ( m_arg_count == 0)        //wrapped function doesn't need args unpacking
        {
            m_fun();
        }
        else
        {
            unpack_args<0>( inputs );
        }
        
        std::string result = "";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        ResultType r1;
        if constexpr ( m_arg_count == 0)        //wrapped function doesn't need args unpacking
        {
          r1 = m_fun();
        }
        else
        {
            r1 = make_call<0>(args);
        }
         
        std::string result = convert_type< ResultType >::to_result (r1);
        return result;
    }      
  }

  //Helper template to unpack and convert each arg in inputs into a parameter pack that
  //can then be passed into the function call
  template < int index, typename... TArgs >
  ResultType unpack_args( std::vector<std::string> const& inputs, TArgs... targs)
  {
    using CurrentArgType = std::tuple_element_t< index, ArgTypes >;

    if constexpr (index + 1 == m_arg_count) //all args unpacked - call function
    {
       return m_fun( targs..., convert_type< CurrentArgType >::from_arg( inputs[index]) );  
    }
    else 
    {
       //unpack next argument in list and keep going
       return make_call< index + 1 >(args, targs..., convert_type< CurrentArgType >::from_arg( inputs[index]));
    }
  }

private:
  std::function< R(Args...) > m_fun;

};


//Example usage.

int add_numbers(int in1, int in2)
{
  return in1 + in2;
}


int main ()
{  
  fun_wrapper< int(int, int) > add_numbers_wrapper(add_numbers);

  std::vector<std::string> args = {"18", "24"};
  cout << add_numbers_wrapper( args ) << endl;   //outputs "42"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did a similar thing using `std::index_sequence` that might be a bit clearer, but I'm not sure myself. https://github.com/sdilts/Salmon/blob/master/include/vm/builtinfunction.hpp

Comment: @Soupy - Your example looks good - it looks like should be better performing too: requiring a smaller function stack than mine. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the right approach, but can indeed be simplified a lot. Let's start with string conversion. Consider that you want to use `std::to_string()` in most cases, but want to add some overloads for types it does not support (like `void`). Instead of creating a class template, consider just adding overloads. Since you are not allowed to overload `std::to_string()` itself, use this trick:

```
using std::to_string; // pull in all overloads from std:: into the global namespace

std::string to_string(void) // your own private overload
{
    return {};
}
```

You also want a `from_string()`, but instead of a class template it can be a function template:

```
template<typename T>
T from_string(std::string const &);

template<>
int from_string(std::string const &arg)
{
    return std::stoi(arg);
}
```

Apart from saving some lines of code when adding support for new to/from string conversion, it also makes usage shorter, compare:

```
convert_type<CurrentArgType>::from_arg(inputs[index])
```

Versus:

```
from_string<CurrentArgType>(inputs[index])
```

A lot of code is spent on unpacking and converting the arguments one by one in a recursive manner. But this can also be improved.
As Soupy mentioned, you can make use of [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), and combined with simultaneous parameter pack expansion and the simplifications mentioned above, this can result in some very compact code. Consider:

```
template<std::size_t... I>
std::string invoke_helper(std::vector<std::string> const& inputs,
                          std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return to_string(m_fun(from_string<Args>(inputs.at(I))...));
}

std::string operator()(std::vector<std::string> const& inputs)
{
    return invoke_helper(inputs, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

You might want to check that `inputs.size() == m_arg_count` first.